# How to append two Strings together in Smali language?

Tags: smali

How to append two Strings together in Smali language?

```
new-instance v9, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invoke-direct {v9}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V
invoke-virtual {v9, v5}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invoke-virtual {v9, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
invoke-virtual {v9}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;
move-result-object v9
```

Comment: Your question already contains the answer. Create a `StringBuilder` and append both String instances from `v5` and `v2` to it. As your question already contains the answer I don't really understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.